# How to specify file path on an umbrella project?

Tags: elixir

I have a Elixir app wich parses XML files. For this application y have some tests to verify that parsing is working well, so I have a XML sample file which is read when the test starts. This sample file is in test folder.

So if I do this to read the file, the test works:

```
xml_sample = File.read("test/sample.xml")
```

My problem is that path is not working when I use an umbrella project to add this application  (and others). I could add complete path like "apps/xml_parser/test/sample.xml", but this app is independent and it could be used in other project, so I want to make the test also independent.

Wich is the best way to manage this kind of file paths?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question's content is different, but my answer will work perfectly for your use case too: `Path.expand/2` with a relative path and `__DIR__`.

Comment: You are right. Content is different, but the solution is the same. Thanks!